# Run code after rendering django

Tags: python, django, multithreading

I've got my Raspberry Pi Camera.
This is like a security cam, so I want to load the front end and then start updating an image 20 times per second from the server side and refresh an image tag each 20 seconds in the client side. The thing is that the server-side loop is infinite (unless you pause it) so the page never renders. I want to render the front end, close the connection and then do the rest. I tried threads, but don't work as expected.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import camera
import time
from threading import Thread

class Preview(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
    def run(self):
        camera.module.preview()

class Render(Thread):
    def __init__(self, request):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.request = request
    def run(self):
        return render(self.request, "dashboard/home.html")

def home(request):
    preview=Preview(); preview.setName("Previewer");
    render = Render(request); render.setName("Renderer");
    render.start(); render.join();
    time.sleep(1)
    preview.start(); preview.join();
```

I know I can have another script and run it through ajax. This is my current status, but I want to do it just once, so how I explained. Any suggestions?

Comment: why can't you just rewrite the image continuously in a standalone script?

Comment: @Fabricator thanks for your help but i am already using VLC for this now. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process that updates the image must be run asynchronously, independent from your Django views. Your Django view can just return the latest image and return, perhaps start up the asynchronous task if it's not running yet.

It's common to use [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) for this.

Comment: I'll look through that in the future, but right now I'm fine with the ajax if it is that much complicated. Thank you anyway.

Comment: It's not *that* complicated, Celery integrates with Django quite well. Once it's configured, you can turn functions into background tasks with a decorator. We include it by default in all our sites, so anything slow can be done after a page is sent back to the user.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it, but I might need a tutorial. :) And remember this is for a RPI, so it may not have enough RAM and Processor to run a threaded task. ):

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done that way. HTTP just doesn't work that way. Your Django view must return one snapshot at a time. On your front-end add javascript code to send request to Django for new snapshot. Of course 20times per second is too much. It looks like you need to stream your camera output to the browser, not create 20 snapshots per second with Django ;)

Comment: ok :) but it works fine for me, with starting the camera preview apart from the script, I'm getting 10-15 frames per second without complicating my life with video streaming. The image is replaced over each time, and javascript creates a new image tag each 100 milliseconds.